# how to have 2 different setting page with inappSettings

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, settings.bundle, inappsettingskit

Hi guys i will like to have 2 different setting page to show 2 different setting

current i'm able to do in 1 setting view, how will i be able to separate into 2 different setting page ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you create two different views in your setting page and use the view which ever is required.

Comment: dont worry about the info(it can be from anywhere) you just want to add two different views right?

Comment: i'm using story board, i setting the view as the inAppSettings Kit view, so it will load from the plist, not very sure how to do it later on

Comment: from the Object library in IB drag one more view and configure it the same way you did the first one..and dont forget to mention that view in .h file(i.e IBOutlet UiView *second view)  and do all @property thing and connect that view in IB to files owner

Comment: nope is not the way of it, i mean i'm using inappsettingskit to generate the table, i did not set anything

Comment: i merged both setting together